# Aligning image to navigationBarTitle in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to add a User Image (button) next to the .navigationBarTitle, but with the code bellow, the image appears on top of the title alignment. (picture attached). Many thanks for your help!

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Watch"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                    Image("User")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                )
```

[Image should be bottom - aligned to the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzqDh.png)

Comment: This is default area for default navigation bar items. You can offset it, but space remains anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This code produces this view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Chocolate")
                Text("Vanilla")
                Text("Strawberry")
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("Watch"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Image(systemName: "person.circle")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding(.top, 90)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

There is a default space for the Items and a default space for the Text. Imagine it like two HStacks in a VStack. Where the Title is in the lower HStack and the items are in the upper one. There is no "real" way on getting in the lower one.
I'd recommend to create an own NavigationBar for your purposes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Simon for your quick answer. The visual result is what I was looking for, but the "user image" does not disappear at the time of scrolling Up. But you brought a great Idea!!! Now I've added the icon to the first line (HStack) with a .offset -55. Therefore, when I scroll up, the icon dissapear under the NavBar. !!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Simon, the best option for what I was looking for is to Add the User Icon to the Title (not NavBar) and apply an Offset of y: -55. When scrolling up the icon disappears under the NavBar. The same effect on the Apple TV app (mobile).` VStack(alignment: .leading) {
HStack {
Text("Children")
.font(.title)
.fontWeight(.bold)
.padding(.leading, 24)
.padding(.top, 20)

```
                        Spacer ()
                        Image("User")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .offset(y: -55)
                            .padding(.trailing, 24)[final result][1]`
```

Comment: Padding works visually (elevate the button to the NavBar Title), but the action for the Button remains on the original (now empty) space. :( ... so, problem not solved.